# Object in the back, visible in the front

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, camera

In the 3D view I have a tree behind a house, but despite that the tree is behind the house and way back in the scene, it's just in front of the camera! How come it's like this? I have used a skin modifier to create the tree. Other objects looks like they should depending on their position.

Here is a picture. The leafs on the tree are OK and not visible, just the 
tree trunk and branches.

[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot so we can see this more clearly ?

Comment: @Shams I added an image

Comment: Check that you did not put a check mark beside x-ray in display section for the tree trunk (you will find it in object section in properties panel)

Comment: @Shams The x-ray was the problem! Thanks for the help! Question solved.

Comment: @Shams Why don't you post an answer (maybe include a screen shot so that others who may come across the question can understand easily) and we can knock this out of the unanswered queue. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem is that the x-ray was checked

when the x-ray is disabled the object in back can't be seen like in the photo and when it is enabled it goes front off everything.

**For example the back cube (orange) isn't visible clearly because x-ray isn't checked**
[image]

**But in this photo it is checked look :**
[image]

this checkbox is used in many things like making/creating/assinging bones without it we could not see the bones:
[image]

**This Checkbox Can be found here : (Properties panel --> Object --> Display)**

[image]